# How to import script tag with data attribute in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, razorpay, script-tag

**I want to import Razorpay button in React so that i can accept payment. But it is not showing in my component.**

**Razorpay Button Code:-**

```
<form>
 <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js" data-payment_button_id="pl_G8bIDza4zHQRfm"> 
 </script> 
</form>
```

**I have tried this to achieve this but failed:-**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './Homepage.css';

const Homepage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js';
    script['data-payment_button_id'] = 'pl_G8bIDza4zHQRfm';
    script.async = true;
    const element = document.querySelector('#home form');
    element.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      element.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section id='home'>
      <form></form>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

**For docs refer to:-** https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-button/donations/#step-3-embed-payment-button-code-in-website

Comment: should be .querySelector('#home') not .querySelector('#home form'), and it better to append script in headers

Comment: Use the setAttribute function--> script.setAttribute('data-payment_button_id', 'pl_G8bIDza4zHQRfm');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the `data-attribute` you can use [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
script.setAttribute('data-payment_button_id', 'pl_G8bIDza4zHQRfm');
```

I recommend you to use the `useRef` hook and get the form reference:

```
const form = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js';
    script.setAttribute('data-payment_button_id', 'pl_G8bIDza4zHQRfm');
    script.async = true;
    
    form.current.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      form.current.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section id='home'>
      <form ref={form}></form>
    </section>
  );
```